# Can the harmonic sum $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ be efficiently computed?

Tags: asymptotics, harmonic-numbers

Can the harmonic sum $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ be efficiently computed?

$H_n$ can be computed in
$n$ reciprocals and adds.
Is there a way
of getting the exact
rational sum
in $o(n)$ operations?

An operation is an
add, subtract,
multiply or divide
of rational numbers.

A possible start is
$H_{2n}
=\frac{1}{2}H_n+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k-1}
$,
but this does not
reduce the number of operations.

I am not concerned with
the fact that rational operations
will take longer for
larger numerators and
denominators,
though taking this
into account
would be interesting.

I am aware that
the denominator would be
$\text{lcm}(1, 2,\dots, n)
\sim e^n
$
and that $H_n$ has
an asymptotic expansion of the form
$\ln(n)+\gamma+\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{a_k}{n^k}
$.